# How do I clear list of pair

Tags: c++, list, stl, std-pair

I want to clear adj list from main function for each test case.

```
class Graph
{
long long int V;    // No. of vertices
list< pair<long long int,long long int> > *adj;

public:
Graph(long long int V);  // Constructor

//clear previous values
void clearList();
};
void Graph::clearList()
{
//WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since it's a pointer to a list, you should check for its existence first.  And you need to decide if you want to keep the object it's pointing to after you clear it, but this would clear it:

```
void Graph::clearList()
{
    if ( adj ) {
        adj->clear();
    }
}
```

*edit*: Couple of side notes depending on what you're doing... if the number of vertices member variable V is what's in your list, just use adj->size() for that.  You should also consider not using a pointer to your list and just using a list directly to avoid manual lifetime management of adj in Graph.  Finally, your constructor implies you're declaring the number of vertices up front, maybe another container is more suitable, like a vector?